# Seleccionar una cantidad y aplicar las funciones a esa cantidad

Tags: javascript

Necesito obtener una cantidad máxima para poder trabajar solo en esa cantidad. ¿cómo hago?

```js
function add() {

    for (var i = 0; i < esto.length; i++) {

        if(esto.length >= 15) { //De estos 15 necesito que obtenga 5 no más y poder trabajar en esa cantidad

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Al parecer ya llevas bastante tiempo en el sitio, tal vez debas volver a leer [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si te refieres a los primeros 5 puedes evaluar el valor de i de tu for para que en cuanto sea igual a 5 cierre el bucle, mientras que sea menor a 5 puedes agregar los valores a otro array.

```js
var esto = ['hola', 'como' , 'estas', 'necesitas', 'ayuda'];
var resultado = [];

function add() {
  for (var i = 0; i < esto.length; i++) {

    if(i <= 2) {
      resultado.push(esto[i]);
    }
  }
  
  console.log(resultado);

}

add();
```

Comment: que estúpido, como no lo pude imaginar, gracias.

Comment: No hay preguntas tontas, hay tontos que no preguntan. Saludos.